# Filter button click functionality

Tags: javascript, button, filter

I am making a menu of the first 9 Pokemon and adding all the info/pics dynamically with JavaScript. Everything appears on the screen but when I try and click to filter the Pokemon by their type, nothing happens. There is no error in the console and I am not sure what the problem is. I have attached the code here and any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>brand new</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="btn-container">
        <button class="filter-btn">Grass</button>
    </div>
    <div class="section-center">
        <div class="pokemon-item">
            <img src="images/bulbasaur.png" alt="bulbasaur" class="photo">
            <h2>Bulbasaur</h2>
            <h3>#<span class="number">1</span></h3>
            <h4>Type<span class="type">Grass</span></h4>
        </div>

    </div>


    <script>
        const pokemon = [
            {
                name: 'Bulbasaur',
                image: 'images/bulbasaur.png',
                number: 1,
                type: 'Grass'
            },

            {
                name: 'Ivysaur',
                image: 'images/ivysaur.png',
                number: 2,
                type: 'Grass'
            },

            {
                name: 'Venusaur',
                image: 'images/venusaur.png',
                number: 3,
                type: 'Grass'
            },

            {
                name: 'Charmander',
                image: 'images/charmander.png',
                number: 4,
                type: 'Fire'
            },

            {
                name: 'Charmeleon',
                image: 'images/charmeleon.png',
                number: 5,
                type: 'Fire'
            },

            {
                name: 'Charizard',
                image: 'images/charizard.png',
                number: 6,
                type: 'Fire'
            },

            {
                name: 'Squirtle',
                image: 'images/squirtle.png',
                number: 7,
                type: 'Water'
            },

            {
                name: 'Wartortle',
                image: 'images/wartortle.png',
                number: 8,
                type: 'Water'
            },

            {
                name: 'Blastoise',
                image: 'images/blastoise.png',
                number: 9,
                type: 'Water'
            }

        ]

        const sectionCenter = document.querySelector('.section-center');
        const btnContainer = document.querySelector('.btn-container');

        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            displayPokemonMenu();
            displayMenuButtons()
        })

        function displayPokemonMenu(array) {
            let pokemonMap = pokemon.map(function (item) {
                return `<div class="pokemon-item">
            <img src="${item.image}" alt="${item.name}" class="photo">
            <h2>${item.name}</h2>
            <h3>#<span class="number">${item.number}</span></h3>
            <h4>Type<span class="type">${item.type}</span></h4>
        </div>`
            }).join('');
            sectionCenter.innerHTML = pokemonMap;
        }

        function displayMenuButtons() {
            const types = pokemon.reduce(function(values, item){
                if(!values.includes(item.type)){
                    values.push(item.type);
                }
                return values
            },
            ['All']
            );

            const typeBtns = types.map(function(type){
                return `<button class="filter-btn">${type}</button>`
            }).join('');

            btnContainer.innerHTML = typeBtns;

            const filterBtns = btnContainer.querySelectorAll('.filter-btn');

            filterBtns.forEach(function(btn){
                btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                    let type = e.currentTarget.dataset.id;
                    let pokemonFilter = pokemon.filter(function(item){
                        if(type === item. type){
                            return item;
                        }
                    })
                    if(type === 'All'){
                        displayPokemonMenu(pokemon);
                    } else {
                        displayPokemonMenu(pokemonFilter);
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: check `type` returns value. I consoled it and it returns `undefined`. I changed it to `let type = e.currentTarget.innerText;` then it returns each type.

Comment: Thank you for bringing that to my attention. It turns out that I forgot to add the data-id into the button tag as I originally intended to do. I fixed that issue so now it's `<button class="filter-btn" data-id="Grass">Grass</button>` and I left `type` as it previously was. When I console `type`, it returns each type but the Pokemon are not being filtered when I click. Is there something wrong with my filter?

Answer (score 0):

Put the array to filter in `displayPokemonMenu()` function. Whenever click each buttons only `pokemon` is filtered in the function. At  `btn.addEventListener('click')` filtering worked with the `type` to return filtered array. This array should be used as argument in `displayPokemonMenu()` function but never used. I attached example below,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>brand new</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="btn-container">
        <button class="filter-btn">Grass</button>
    </div>
    <div class="section-center">
        <div class="pokemon-item">
            <img src="images/bulbasaur.png" alt="bulbasaur" class="photo">
            <h2>Bulbasaur</h2>
            <h3>#<span class="number">1</span></h3>
            <h4>Type<span class="type">Grass</span></h4>
        </div>

    </div>


    <script>
        const pokemon = [
            {
                name: 'Bulbasaur',
                image: 'images/bulbasaur.png',
                number: 1,
                type: 'Grass'
            },

            {
                name: 'Ivysaur',
                image: 'images/ivysaur.png',
                number: 2,
                type: 'Grass'
            },

            {
                name: 'Venusaur',
                image: 'images/venusaur.png',
                number: 3,
                type: 'Grass'
            },

            {
                name: 'Charmander',
                image: 'images/charmander.png',
                number: 4,
                type: 'Fire'
            },

            {
                name: 'Charmeleon',
                image: 'images/charmeleon.png',
                number: 5,
                type: 'Fire'
            },

            {
                name: 'Charizard',
                image: 'images/charizard.png',
                number: 6,
                type: 'Fire'
            },

            {
                name: 'Squirtle',
                image: 'images/squirtle.png',
                number: 7,
                type: 'Water'
            },

            {
                name: 'Wartortle',
                image: 'images/wartortle.png',
                number: 8,
                type: 'Water'
            },

            {
                name: 'Blastoise',
                image: 'images/blastoise.png',
                number: 9,
                type: 'Water'
            }

        ]

        const sectionCenter = document.querySelector('.section-center');
        const btnContainer = document.querySelector('.btn-container');

        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            displayPokemonMenu();
            displayMenuButtons()
        })

        function displayPokemonMenu(array) {        
        /////
        if (array === undefined) array = pokemon
        /////
            let pokemonMap = array.map(function (item) {
                return `<div class="pokemon-item">
            <img src="${item.image}" alt="${item.name}" class="photo">
            <h2>${item.name}</h2>
            <h3>#<span class="number">${item.number}</span></h3>
            <h4>Type<span class="type">${item.type}</span></h4>
        </div>`
            }).join('');
            //here result is one filterd with pokemon only
            //console.log(pokemonMap)
            sectionCenter.innerHTML = pokemonMap;
        }

        function displayMenuButtons() {
            const types = pokemon.reduce(function(values, item){
                if(!values.includes(item.type)){
                    values.push(item.type);
                }
                return values
            },
            ['All']
            );

            const typeBtns = types.map(function(type){
                return `<button class="filter-btn">${type}</button>`
            }).join('');

            btnContainer.innerHTML = typeBtns;

            const filterBtns = btnContainer.querySelectorAll('.filter-btn');

            filterBtns.forEach(function(btn){
                btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                    let type = e.currentTarget.innerText;
                    let pokemonFilter = pokemon.filter(function(item){
                        if(type === item. type){
                        //filtering was successful here
                        //console.log(item)
                            return item;
                        }
                    })
                    // pokemonFilter filtered successfully,
                    //console.log(pokemonFilter);
                    if(type === 'All'){
                        displayPokemonMenu(pokemon);
                    } else {
                        displayPokemonMenu(pokemonFilter);
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>brand new</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="btn-container">
        <button class="filter-btn">Grass</button>
    </div>
    <div class="section-center">
        <div class="pokemon-item">
            <img src="images/bulbasaur.png" alt="bulbasaur" class="photo">
            <h2>Bulbasaur</h2>
            <h3>#<span class="number">1</span></h3>
            <h4>Type<span class="type">Grass</span></h4>
        </div>

    </div>


    <script>
        const pokemon = [
            {
                name: 'Bulbasaur',
                image: 'images/bulbasaur.png',
                number: 1,
                type: 'Grass'
            },

            {
                name: 'Ivysaur',
                image: 'images/ivysaur.png',
                number: 2,
                type: 'Grass'
            },

            {
                name: 'Venusaur',
                image: 'images/venusaur.png',
                number: 3,
                type: 'Grass'
            },

            {
                name: 'Charmander',
                image: 'images/charmander.png',
                number: 4,
                type: 'Fire'
            },

            {
                name: 'Charmeleon',
                image: 'images/charmeleon.png',
                number: 5,
                type: 'Fire'
            },

            {
                name: 'Charizard',
                image: 'images/charizard.png',
                number: 6,
                type: 'Fire'
            },

            {
                name: 'Squirtle',
                image: 'images/squirtle.png',
                number: 7,
                type: 'Water'
            },

            {
                name: 'Wartortle',
                image: 'images/wartortle.png',
                number: 8,
                type: 'Water'
            },

            {
                name: 'Blastoise',
                image: 'images/blastoise.png',
                number: 9,
                type: 'Water'
            }

        ]

        const sectionCenter = document.querySelector('.section-center');
        const btnContainer = document.querySelector('.btn-container');

        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            displayPokemonMenu();
            displayMenuButtons()
        })

        function displayPokemonMenu(array) {        
        /////
        if (array === undefined) array = pokemon
        /////
            let pokemonMap = array.map(function (item) {
                return `<div class="pokemon-item">
            <img src="${item.image}" alt="${item.name}" class="photo">
            <h2>${item.name}</h2>
            <h3>#<span class="number">${item.number}</span></h3>
            <h4>Type<span class="type">${item.type}</span></h4>
        </div>`
            }).join('');
            //here result is one filterd with pokemon only
            //console.log(pokemonMap)
            sectionCenter.innerHTML = pokemonMap;
        }

        function displayMenuButtons() {
            const types = pokemon.reduce(function(values, item){
                if(!values.includes(item.type)){
                    values.push(item.type);
                }
                return values
            },
            ['All']
            );

            const typeBtns = types.map(function(type){
                return `<button class="filter-btn">${type}</button>`
            }).join('');

            btnContainer.innerHTML = typeBtns;

            const filterBtns = btnContainer.querySelectorAll('.filter-btn');

            filterBtns.forEach(function(btn){
                btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                    let type = e.currentTarget.innerText;
                    let pokemonFilter = pokemon.filter(function(item){
                        if(type === item. type){
                        //filtering was successful here
                        //console.log(item)
                            return item;
                        }
                    })
                    // pokemonFilter filtered successfully,
                    //console.log(pokemonFilter);
                    if(type === 'All'){
                        displayPokemonMenu(pokemon);
                    } else {
                        displayPokemonMenu(pokemonFilter);
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).